# How I create renderview func as static one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use  renderview function as a static function , what I need
 to do?

public static string RenderView(string viewName, object model)

```
public string RenderView(string viewName, object model)
                {
                    ViewData.Model = model;
                    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                                 viewName);
                        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                                     ViewData, TempData, sw);
                        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create static function like this

```
public static class Util
{
    public static string RenderView(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                        viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                            ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call this function like this:
`Util.RenderView("_viewName",Model)`

Comment: i want to use the function in controller and not in the view

Comment: some of the vars in the func cannot be in static field like ViewData and ControllerContext i get erros

Comment: you need to pass them as arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the Controller in itsself into the static method and access all the properties from the Controller like ControllerContext, ViewData, TempData.

The call would be like this (this is the Controller object)

```
RenderView(this, "_viewName", model)
```

The static method would look like this:

```
public static string RenderView(ControllerBase controller,
    string viewName,
    object model)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext,
                                                                    viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                        controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```